# randomise cycle content in jquery jcycle plugin

Tags: jquery

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Is is possible to randomise the cycled content with the jquery jcycle plugin?

Cheers

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `random` option for this, set it to `1` (or `true`), like this:

```
$('#myDiv').cycle({ 
  fx: 'cover', 
  random: 1
});
```

[See the demo here](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/begin.html) and [full options list here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html).

Answer (score 1):

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

There is a `random` option in the option reference. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

probably this:

random:   0,     // true for random, false for sequence (not applicable to shuffle fx)